# How do I pass information from a multi-selection JTree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, multi-select

I am writing a program that will print information based on selections in a JTree. Multi-selection is enabled, but I haven't been able to figure out how to find out which nodes are selected. Because it is a very large tree, I would prefer to have a Vector of selections which is updated each time a selection/deselection is made, instead of scanning the tree when the print button is pressed. What is the best way of doing this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`getSelectionPaths()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#getSelectionPaths%28%29) which will return all selected nodes.